# How do I use the Spectre Specs?

Tags: lego-harry-potter-years-5-7

In the level Year 5 - Chapter 2 - A Trip to Hogsmeade, near the very beginning of the level, there is a pile of LEGO that is transparent, and a message pops up saying to use the Spectre Specs to see hidden LEGO pieces.

What are these? Where do I find them in the game?

Comment: Just equip them in one of the Spy's Misc slo... oh wait, this isn't [tag:team-fortress-2].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a dispenser close by where you can get a pair.  You might need to be in "Free Play" for this to show up.  Check out this video:

Comment: The video is interesting, but it is not the same level I am asking about. :(

Comment: Huh, that's the first time in the game that I remember seeing them.  I'm looking at a video guide for the level you mention, but I don't see them encountering the situation you're talking about.

Comment: Edited, check out this video and see if it helps.  I found one where they're replaying the Hogsmeade level, and in the first 3 seconds they run and grab some SpectreSpecs.

Comment: I don't know if it matters that I am playing the DS version - the level I am in is all wintery and you have to find students in the snow.

Comment: Oh, I see now! That helps. I suspect a big part of my problem is that the DS graphics are terrible, so seeing things like that is next to impossible.